# QNX 6.6 Windows Host - Flashing image in USB flash drive

Tags: windows, host, qnx

I have installed QNX 6.6 SDP in Windows host.

Have created an ifs image using mkifs command.

I have created FAT32 partition of the USB drive and copied the filesystem to it. But I am unsure of the following:

1) How to create QNX loader using dinit
2) How and where to copy the ifs image

Can anyone pls guide me / provide pointers to resolving this?

Comment: Do you make image for x86 target?

Comment: @DmitryTabakov The image is for x86 target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://community.qnx.com/sf/frs/do/downloadFile/projects.bsp/frs.qnx_sdp_6_6_bsp_for_generic_x86.bsp_user_guide_for_the_generic_x/frs58795?dl=1) is a guide with couple of methods for boot from USB and creating your own image.